# How can I make a random number/letter generator?

Tags: batch-file, random

Hello guys I am very bad at notepad, I want to make a random code generator.

That Generates codes like this 3K2EU-ZGS5L-P3DNL-YM9JC
I want it to work with a notepad .bat file so I can let it run on my PC

Comment: Add a tag for the programming language you wish to use to generate this code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using %random% values to assign numbers and letters as demonstrated 
below. If you need letters and numbers in specific places within the 20 digits, 
adjust the Condition used to call getLetters or Getnumber to call according to current 
%dig%==number

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion

:open
Set dig=0

:main
Set /a dig=%dig% + 1
CALL :digit%dig%
Call LetorNum
IF %dig%==20 goto result

GOTO main

:LetorNum
Set /a pick=%random% * 2 / 32768 + 1
IF %pick%==1 call :getLetter
IF %pick%==2 call :getNumber
GOTO :EOF

:getLetter
Set /a Letter=%random% * 26 / 32768 + 1
IF %letter%==1 Set disp!dig!=a
```

REM repeat for each letter value between a and z

```
IF %letter%==26 Set disp!dig!=z
GOTO :EOF

:getNumber
Set /a number=%random% * 10 / 32768 + 1
IF %number%==1 Set disp!dig!=0
```

REM repeat for every number value between zero and 9

```
IF %number%==9 Set disp!dig!=9
GOTO :EOF

:result
ECHO %disp1%%disp2%%disp3%%disp4%%disp5%-%disp6%%disp7%%disp8%%disp9%%disp10%- 
%disp11%%disp12%%disp13%%disp14%%disp15%-%disp16%%disp17%%disp18%%disp19%%disp20%
pause >nul
GOTO open
```